Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange and TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
I'm displaying the movie data that I've brought in open api in card format. I'd like to newly arrange them in the order of title a-z and highest stars in drop-down format. However, it does not work when I select another item after the initial card is loaded I thought it was a problem with the function, so I used console.log, but the function works fine.

Uncaught ReferenceError: handleSortChange is not defined
The error at HTMLSelectElement.onchange appears
And also sort.js:50 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
at sortByTitle (sort.js:4:17)
at handleSortChange
These are errors I have

If I use console.log to see if I get the api well, it shows up as undefined
I put <script src="./src/sort.js" type="module"></script> in the header of index.html because it said it had to be loaded before the script was executed
sort.js
import { callGetMoviesAPI, displayMovieData } from "./movieAPI.js";

const sortByTitle = (movies) => {
  return movies.slice().sort((a, b) => {
    const titleA = a.title.toUpperCase();
    const titleB = b.title.toUpperCase();
    if (titleA < titleB) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (titleA > titleB) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
};

const sortByRating = (movies) => {
  return movies.slice().sort((a, b) => b.vote_average - a.vote_average);
};
const movies = [
  { title: "B", vote_average: 8.5 },
  { title: "A", vote_average: 7.9 },
  { title: "C", vote_average: 9.2 }
];

console.log("Sorted by title:", sortByTitle(movies));
console.log("Sorted by rating:", sortByRating(movies));

const handleSortChange = async (value) => {
  try {
    const movies = await callGetMoviesAPI();
    console.log("Movies from callGetMoviesAPI:", movies); // Movies from callGetMoviesAPI: undefined

    switch (value) {
      case "default":
        displayMovieData(movies);
        break;
      case "title":
        const sortedMoviesByTitle = sortByTitle(movies);
        displayMovieData(sortedMoviesByTitle);
        break;
      case "rating":
        const sortedMoviesByRating = sortByRating(movies);
        displayMovieData(sortedMoviesByRating);
        break;
      default:
        displayMovieData(movies);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

export { handleSortChange };

main.js
import { handleSortChange } from "./sort.js";
import { callGetMoviesAPI, displayMovieData } from "./movieAPI.js";
import { search_movie } from "./search.js";

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const searchMovies = urlParams.get("search");

const movies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("movies"));

if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("movies")) === null) {
  console.log("----load move datas----");
  callGetMoviesAPI();
} else if (searchMovies === null) {
  const filteredMovieData = movies.map((movie) => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(movie)));
  displayMovieData(filteredMovieData);
} else {

  let contentMovie = search_movie(searchMovies);
  displayMovieData(contentMovie);
}


document.getElementById("sort").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  handleSortChange(event.target.value);
});

index.html
<body>
    <movie-header></movie-header>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <label for="sort">arrange</label>:</label>
      <select id="sort" onchange="handleSortChange(this.value)">
        <option value="default">defalut</option>
        <option value="title">title</option>
        <option value="rating">rating</option>
      </select>
    </div>

I'm sorry if my question was rude. I'm a novice at developing and this is my first question. I'm SO confusing...
I checked with console.log to see where and what was going on, and I looked up similar questions in stack overflow, but I'm not sure. When I select drop-down, I want to see a list of newly sorted cards

Functions defined in a module are not in the global scope used by onXXX attributes. Use addEventListener().
